# Context menu to delete foo inside a Table

Tags: javascript, electron

I want a context menu only to delete foo inside a HTML table.

I use [electron-context-menu](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-context-menu).

I thought I could use mediaType for html table but I can't.

```
const contextMenu = require('electron-context-menu');

contextMenu({
    prepend: (defaultActions, params, browserWindow) => [
        {
            label: 'Rainbow',
            // Only show it when right-clicking images
            visible: params.mediaType === 'image' // <--- Here ? mediaType === 'table' ?
        }
    ]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, thank to this [post](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-context-menu/issues/49#issuecomment-420830781) (and [Titus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1552587/titus) which oriented my research)

The code look like this :

```
shouldShowMenu: (event, { x, y }) => {
    const elements = $(document.elementsFromPoint(x, y));    
    const elementfiltered = $(elements.filter('td')[0]).parent();    
    if (elementfiltered[0]) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Post full link : https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-context-menu/issues/49#issuecomment-420830781

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [shouldShowMenu](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-context-menu#shouldshowmenu) property, something like this:

```
{
  shouldShowMenu: (event, params) => !!event.target.closest('table')
}
```

`event.target.closest('table')` will check if the element on which the context menu was triggered is a `<table>` or any of its parents are.

Comment: Thank you for reply.
But this give the error : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'closest' of undefined".

I will search while waiting for reply ^^

Comment: I found something useful : https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-context-menu/issues/49#issuecomment-420830781